# Azure DevOps Services REST API: What is the equivalent to: git branch --contains <commit>

Tags: azure, rest, devops

I use the Azure DevOps Services REST API, my problem is to identify a merge coming from stage.

The idea would be to get the iterations and the commits, and from each commit find the parent and see if it is already in stage. That would mean that a particular commit is a merge from stage.

The problem is that I don't find a way to know if a commit is already in stage. This is where I would expect something like ***contains*** in die API. Is there something like this ?
Or an alternative ?

```
    git branch --contains <commit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you explored the following Azure DevOps Rest API endpoint:

> GET [https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=4.1](https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/commits?searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=master&api-version=4.1)

Ref: [Azure DevOps Git Commits - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)

***Sample Response:***

[image]